# subprocess.Popen() performance degrades as process count rises

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have an application that runs and manages many services using `subprocess.Popen()`.  Each of these services runs until it is explicitly told to come down.  I'm noticing that the time to return from the `subprocess.Popen()` call increases at a fairly linear rate as more processes are spawned by the arbiter.

My basic code looks like this:

```
process_list = []
for command in command_list:
  start_tm = time.time()
  process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  end_tm = time.time()
  print end_tm-start_tm
  process_list.append(process)
```

I'm seeing that the print of `end_tm-start_tm` increases as I spawn more and more processes.  The services run by each `command` can be in any order and I see the same behavior.  The time increase isn't completely linear but I keep seeing a pattern: the first process takes ~0.005 seconds to spawn, the 10th takes ~0.125 seconds, the 20th takes ~0.35 seconds, and so on.

My arbiter process runs upwards of 100 subprocesses.  I could split it up so that multiple arbiters run with a smaller number of subprocesses each but I want to understand what the issue is first.  Is the overhead of one process owning many subprocesses so great that each additional subprocess adds to the return time of `subprocess.Popen()`?  Is there anything I could do to potentially mitigate that?

EDIT: I split my single arbiter process into two.  In my previous test, my arbiter was running 64 processes.  I created two separate configurations of my arbiter that each ran 32 processes.  I ran the first arbiter, let it completely start all 32 processes, then kicked off the second arbiter.

In both cases, the first process again took ~0.005 seconds to start up and the 32nd and final process took about ~0.45 seconds to start up.  In my previous test of a single arbiter with 64 processes, the first process took ~0.005 seconds to start while the 64th would take roughly 0.85 seconds.

Comment: You are running 100 processes in parallel. So each process has to share your CPU with all others.

Comment: The performance of the processes themselves isn't the problem though.  Each process performs well.  It's the spawning of those processes that seems to take an escalating amount of time.

Comment: I'm unconvinced that this isn't overhead at the OS level, unrelated to anything Python is doing. Using a tool such as [Sysdig](https://sysdig.com/opensource/) to measure actual time for `fork()` and `execve()` operations to complete could do a great deal to allay that suspicion.

Comment: (Actually *trying* your proposed solution -- of having multiple supervisors and seeing if the same effect takes place -- would similarly provide a useful datapoint).

Comment: ...it'd also be interesting to determine whether this is fork or execv overhead -- if the former, perhaps your use case calls for a prefork pool or similar, in which case you might consider using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for a 3rd-party-maintained, pre-optimized job pool implementation.

Comment: Hmm. There *is* some overhead that goes up as you have more processes, just in closing the forked-off process's copy of your various FDs if they weren't created with the nofork flag, but I wouldn't expect that to be the level of sigificant you're reporting here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll run a test using multiple arbiter processes of smaller subprocess pools and edit my question with the results.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've edited the original question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: has nothing to do with process structure creation, but only with process scheduling.

Comment: @Daniel, *what* "has nothing to do with process structure creation"? One of the items I was discussing above (which I'm guessing you were referring to) was the time spent closing FDs that we don't want to pass a subprocess. That certainly *is* a cost that increases as you have more children with their own FIFOs that you don't want to pass, if `O_CLOEXEC` isn't available to ensure that those FDs are already closed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question about "why" what you are noticing is occurring, but I would highly recommend changing strategies for how you are dealing with your multiprocessing by using `ThreadPoolExecutor` to manage system resources.

Since your system can't effectively manage more processes than it has system threads, I would try:

```
>>> from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
>>> from multiprocessing import cpu_count
>>> with ThreadPoolExecutor(workers=cpu_count()) as pool:
    results = pool.map(lambda cmd:  subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE), command_list)
```

I find the API to be easy and the resource managment to be quite effective, and there are less "gotchas".

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown

Although this is for 3.6, the API is largely the same once you `pip install` the `concurrent.futures` module for 2.7.

Comment: might have to change up the code a bit to suit your observation/management purposes

Comment: While it may be a bit quicker to do it liek you suggest, due to the fact that each thread is not starting as many subprocesses each, as per the observation of the OP, your code is not doing what you think it is. Each call to `subprocess.Popen()` is starting a new process, whether done in treads or not. When started, the call returns, allowing the thread to continue to start a another suboprocess. Thus, in the end all subprocesses are running in parallel none-the-less.

Comment: Further, there is nothing saying that the subprocesses are CPU bound and if they are not, the whole idea of limiting the number of processes to the number of CPUs is in vain. Maybe they are waiting for external events to complete (e.g. loading a webpage). Then you get a significant speedup from waiting on them in parallel.

Comment: ah, but that's exactly the point :) using ThreadPool to launch processes using `Popen` is a great technique that lets you leverage the best of Python threading and OS processes.  It's doing exactly what I think it does.  It's up the to the developer to be disciplined enough to manage independent subprocesses launched by Popen

Comment: Why would you run `Popen`in threads? The processes are forked off anyway and your main program will continue to run. You don't need threads for that.

Comment: The non-technical reason is because multiprocessing in Python is a huge pain.  Threading is great, but the GIL doesn't let you do anything fun.  ThreadPool + Popen + serialized data -> `.py` puts the heavy lifting on the OS.

Comment: But you **don't** need the threads for that. At least not if you just use it to call `Popen()`. If you stay in the thread, waiting for the subprocess to finish, that is another matter, and then I can (almost) understand where you are comming from. But, you know, multiprocessing does not have to be a pain. You can use it directly with `concurrent.futures`just by replacing your `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Comment: You are right, in certain applications you can use simple threading.  I wish it were as easy as swapping TPE with PPE... that thing I did with the `lambda`, for instance, would not be possible, since nested function scopes are not serializable constructs.  Passing classes or user instantiated objects is also not an option.  I'm sure we could have a good discussion on the pros and cons and I get a feeling you have a little bit of knowledge regarding stuff the OS is doing that I don't.  I just know for me this has been the most flexible approach.